# jq - convert a list of objects into a summarized object

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a JSON data like this:

```
[
  {
    "tone_id": "anger",
    "score": 0.012,
    "tone_name": "Anger"
  },
  {
    "tone_id": "disgust",
    "score": 0.002,
    "tone_name": "Disgust"
  },
  {
    "tone_id": "fear",
    "score": 0.14,
    "tone_name": "Fear"
  },
  {
    "tone_id": "joy",
    "score": 0.42,
    "tone_name": "Joy"
  }
]
```

I want to convert it into something like the following using **`jq`**:

```
{
  "anger": 0.012,
  "disgust": 0.002,
  "fear": 0.14,
  "joy": 0.42
}
```

Best I could do is:

```
cat result.json | jq '.[] | { (.tone_id): .score }'
```

which gave the following:

```
{
  "anger": 0.012
}
{
  "disgust": 0.002
}
{
  "fear": 0.14
}
{
  "joy": 0.42
}
```

> I know I can easily do this using other methods. Just wanted to know if it's possible using **`jq`** one-liner?

Comment: show, how the potential 3rd and 4th objects should be processed? Extend your input array

Comment: It's just a list of `tone_id` and their respective `score`s... I want as many keys in my final object as the number of elements in the original list.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Exactly how the 1st and 2nd objects are processed. Extract `tone_id` and `score` and make them key, value respectively in the final output. I've added more concrete example above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A single-invocation one-liner:

```
 jq 'map( {(.tone_id): .score} ) | add'
```

(You could also wrap square brackets around `.[] | { (.tone_id): .score }` before passing to `add` — the two approaches are equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `from_entries`:

```
jq '[.[] | {key: .tone_id, value: .score}] | from_entries' tmp.json
# or jq 'map({key: .tone_id, value: .score}) | from_entries' tmp.json
```

although in this case I don't see anything to recommend it over @peak's `add` solution.

Answer (score 0):

With **`reduce`** function:

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $o ({}; .[$o["tone_id"]] = $o["score"])' result.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "anger": 0.012,
  "disgust": 0.002,
  "fear": 0.14,
  "joy": 0.42
}
```